# How to know that a function given below is onto?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :x+y \neq -1\}$
Define $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$f(x,y)=\left[\frac{y}{(1+x+y)},\frac{x}{1+x+y}\right]$$
How to prove that $f(A)=\mathbb{R}^2$ or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The point $(0,1) \in \Bbb R^2$ but $(0,1) \notin f(A)$.

To check this,

Suppose $(0,1) \in f(A)$.

Then $\frac {y}{1+x+y}=0$ and $\frac {x}{1+x+y}=1$

$\Rightarrow y=0$ and $x=1+x+y \Rightarrow x=1+x \Rightarrow 1=0$ which is absurd.

Hence we conclude that $f$ is not onto.

Comment: Using the same argument one shows that the whole line $x+y-1=0$ is disjoint from $f(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be useful to switch coordinates to $(u,v)=(x+y,x-y)$. The function is then
$$ f(u,v) = \frac{1}{1+u}(u,-v) $$
In order for $f$ to be surjective, then, in particular $u\mapsto \frac{u}{1+u}$ must be surjective -- but $\frac{u}{1+u}=1-\frac1{1+u}$ can never be $1$.